# If $Y_i = 1 - X_i$, why is $Y_{(1)} = X_{(n)}$ if $X \sim U(0, 1)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I saw in my notes that if $Y_i = 1 - X_i$, then $Y_{(1)} = X_{(n)}$ if $X_i \sim U(0, 1)$?

Note that $X_{(i)}$ is the i-th order statistic so $X_{(n)} = \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$.

Isn't $Y_{(1)} = \min\{1 - X_1, \ldots, 1 - X_n\}$? If so, wouldn't $Y_{(1)} = X_{(1)}$?

It's possible something may have gotten lost in translation in my notes, but I wanted to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something here.

Comment: It is basically just $\min_i (-x_i) = -\max_i(x_i)$.

Comment: @user10354138 I am not seeing the connection with having negative numbers?

Comment: $-x_i<-x_j$ iff $x_i>x_j$.

Comment: @user10354138 I agree with this, but isn't $Y_{(1)} = \min\{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n\}$ by definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Multiplying the $X_i$ by $-1$ reverses the order: $a <b \iff -a > -b$
- Adding $1$ does not change the order:  $-a > -b \iff 1-a > 1-b$
- So the highest $X_i$ corresponds to the lowest $-X_i$ and the lowest $Y_i=1-X_i$
- So $$Y_{(1)} =\min\{Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n\} \\ = \min\{1-X_1, 1-X_2, \ldots , 1-X_n\}\\ = 1+\min\{-X_1, -X_2, \ldots, -X_n\} \\ = 1-\max\{X_1, X_2, \ldots ,X_n\} \\ =1 -X_{(n)}$$

Comment: I agree with this formula. So this seems to prove my earlier point in that $Y_{(1)} \neq X_{(n)}$? (excluding the case where n = 1)

Comment: $Y_{(1)} =1- X_{(n)}$ so likely to be neither $X_{(n)}$ nor $X_{(1)}$ if $X_{(n)} \not = \frac12$ and $X_{(n)} \not = 1-X_{(1)}$

Comment: Ahh yes. I see.