# How to show that $\operatorname{var}(X_{(1)}) = \operatorname{var}(X_{(n)})$ for $X_i \sim U(0, 1)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, variance, order-statistics

Define $Y_i = 1 - X_i$ and $Y_{(k)}$ as the k-th order statistic, then
$$
Y_{(1)} = 1 - X_{(n)}
$$

Variance is invariant to shifts, so
$$
\operatorname{var}(X_{(n)}) = \operatorname{var}(Y_{(1)}) \\
\operatorname{var}(X_{(1)}) = \operatorname{var}(Y_{(n)}) \\
$$

I am stuck at this point, but I think the proof should somehow follow from these two expressions.

We also know that $\operatorname{var}(X_{i}) = \operatorname{var}(Y_{i})$, but I don't think this (directly) implies that $\operatorname{var}(X_{(1)}) = \operatorname{var}(Y_{(1)})$. If it does, then

$$
\operatorname{var}(X_{(n)}) = \operatorname{var}(Y_{(n)}) = \operatorname{var}(X_{(1)})
$$

Comment: $X$ and $1-X$ has the same law when $X\sim U(0,1)$.  Hence $X_{(n)}$ and $1-X_{(1)}$ has the law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that you are using is perfect. Just note the fact that $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ also follow iid $U(0,1)$ distribution. Hence, $Y_{(k)}$ and $X_{(k)}$ have the same distribution. But by the definition of $Y$, we have $Y_{(k)} = 1-X_{(n-k+1)}$. Using both these facts we have,
$$\mathrm{Var}(Y_{(k)})=\mathrm{Var}(X_{(n-k+1)}){=}\mathrm{Var}(X_{(k)})$$
Putting $k=1$, we get the desired special case.

P.S. Note that this argument is general and holds for every symmetric distribution, symmetric about some $\theta\in\Bbb R$ say. Just define $Y_i=2\theta-X_i$ in that case.

Comment: I think $Y_{(k)} \neq X_{(n - k + 1)}$? This was shown in my earlier post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137596/if-y-i-1-x-i-why-is-y-1-x-n-if-x-sim-u0-1#4137615

Comment: @user5965026 Yeah there was a typo. I've corrected now.

Comment: Ah, the $Y_{(k)}$ and $X_{(k)}$ having the same distribution is what I missed. Can you say they have the same distribution solely because $X_i \sim U(0,1)$ and also $Y_i \sim U(0, 1)$, or would only be complete if you proved it, i.e., that the two have the same PDF?

Comment: @user5965026, The two having the same pdf is a trivial statement in this case (just like in most of the cases). We know that pdf of $a-X$ for any random variable $X$ is $f(a-x)$, where $f(x)$ is the pdf of $X$. In this case, $f(x)$ is the indicator function of interval $(0,1)$, same as $f(1-x)$. Similarly, when $f(x)$ is even, we can directly say that $-X$ has same distribution as $X$.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple and direct way to proceed...

$X_{(1)}$ is the minimum value of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and $X_{(n)}$ is the maximum

Thus

$$f_{X_{(1)}}(t)=n(1-t)^{n-1}$$

$$f_{X_{(n)}}(t)=n t^{n-1}$$

Now it is easy to calculate all the variances with the definition

After some easy calculations in both cases you get

$$V=\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$$

Comment: This approach seems a bit more involved than what I was envisioning. Is there a quick way to deduce the equality from the shift idea that I tried to apply?